# Concatenate columns based on separator in order

Tags: r

I have 2 columns that I would like to concatenate into a single column.  Each column has separators ">" and each row either has the same number of separators or none at all.

```
col1 <- c('A > B > C > B > B > A > B > A > C',
      'A > B',
      'A > C > B',
      'A',
      'A > B > B > C')

col2 <- c('D > E > E > E > F > F > D > F > E',
      'D > F',
      'F > F > E',
      'E',
      'E > F > D > D')

df <- data.frame(col1, col2)
```

I would like to end up with a data frame like this:

```
col1
A|D > B|E > C|E > B|E > B|F > A|F > B|D > A|F > C|E
A|D > B|F
A|F > C|F > B|E
A|E
A|E > B|F > B|D > C|D
```

Comment: My original try comprised of calculating the max number of separators and using that in a split function.

    df$pathlength <- 
    stringr::str_count(df$col1, ">") + 1

    stringr::str_split_fixed(df$col1,">",max(df$pathlength))
    stringr::str_split_fixed(df$col2,">",max(df$pathlength))

This gives 2 data frames with equal number of columns, however, I am not sure how to join the 2 to keep the relationship between each original combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for:

```
mapply(paste,strsplit(col1,' > '),strsplit(col2,' > '),sep='|',collapse=' > ')
[1] "A|D > B|E > C|E > B|E > B|F > A|F > B|D > A|F > C|E"
[2] "A|D > B|F"                                          
[3] "A|F > C|F > B|E"                                    
[4] "A|E"                                                
[5] "A|E > B|F > B|D > C|D"
```